# Tornadofx Tableview row count

Tags: tornadofx

Hey guys can someone please enlighten me. what is the best way to have a label display `SortedFilteredList` size. I have a `tableview` and I want a label showing the current table row count while filtering using `filterwhen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a `StringBinding` towards the `sizeProperty` of the `SortedFilteredList`. I've added an example to the `TableViewSortFilterTest` in the framework, check out https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/tornadofx/testapps/TableViewSortFilterTest.kt for a complete example. Here I add an informational hbox to the bottom of the screen:

```
hbox(5) {
    label("Filter count:")
    label(data.sizeProperty.stringBinding { "$it records matching filter" })
}
```

The `data` property is my `SortedFilteredList` instance.

Comment: Brilliant Thank You!